# How to convert CSV to Excel using Python with pandas in Apache NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi, data-processing

How to convert CSV raw source from `GenerateFlowFile` processor to Excel file using processor `ExecuteStreamCommand` or `ExecuteScript`?

And how to run Python virtual env (env) to use dependencies in Python project?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your CSV to Excel logic inside a Python script and call it using `ExecuteStreamCommand`. Start something like below and make changes as per your requirement:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Reading the csv file content from NiFi
csv_df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
  
# send excel file back to NiFi
csv_df.to_excel(sys.stdout.buffer, index=False)
```

Configure your `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor as:

[image: Image of the properties tab in the Processor Details window. Properties and values are: "Command Arguments" - path to the .py file. "Command Path" - python. "Ignore STDIN" - false. "Working Directory" - /scripts (directory of the .py file). "Argument Delimiter" - ';'. "Output Destination Attribute" - No value set. "Max Attribute Length" - 256]

Comment: just chenge from
csv_df.to_excel(sys.stdout, index = False)

to
csv_df.to_excel(sys.stdout.buffer,index=False)

it works great thank you very much

Comment: If the answer helps to solve your problem, please accept it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I run the script. Then the Error "import: not found" occours.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.anoop.converter;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.*;
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.lifecycle.OnScheduled;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.CapabilityDescription;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.SeeAlso;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.Tags;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessSession;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessorInitializationContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Tags({"csvToExcel"})
@CapabilityDescription("This processor can convert CSV flow files into Excel flow file")
@SeeAlso({})
@ReadsAttributes({@ReadsAttribute(attribute="", description="")})
@WritesAttributes({@WritesAttribute(attribute="", description="")})
@InputRequirement(InputRequirement.Requirement.INPUT_REQUIRED)
public class CsvToExcel extends AbstractProcessor {


    public static final Relationship REL_SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("original")
            .description("The original file")
            .build();

    private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;

    private Set<Relationship> relationships;

    @Override
    protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
        descriptors = Collections.emptyList();

        relationships = new HashSet<>();
        relationships.add(REL_SUCCESS);
        relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return this.relationships;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
        return descriptors;
    }

    @OnScheduled
    public void onScheduled(final ProcessContext context) {}

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) {
        FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
        if ( flowFile == null ) {
            return;
        }

        session.write(flowFile, new Converter());
        session.putAttribute(flowFile,"convertedIntoExcel","true");
        session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
    }
}

class Converter implements StreamCallback {

    @Override
    public void process(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        try {
            streamConversion(in,out);
        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void streamConversion(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

        String[] rowData = null;
        int rowNum = 0;
        while ((rowData = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (String cellData : rowData) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                cell.setCellValue(cellData);
            }
        }
        workbook.write(out);
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).